# How can I create an Ubuntu 14.04 live CD from a persistent live usb stick?

Tags: livecd, liveusb

I have installed some apps on the usb stick. The usb works wonderfully and I simply wish to transplant it onto DVDs. I created an .img file of the USB stick and burned it onto DVD, but it didn't work.

I made the liveUSB using startup usb creator. When I diffed the files on official distro and my USB, I could see that `syslinux` directory is just there. Why didn't it work on DVD? What should I do to make the DVD bootable?

I'm not sure this is going to be very complicated or very simple. Thanks